# How (mathematically) does pressure in the intake manifold vary based on size of throttle opening?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, automotive-engineering, pressure, airflow

I have the intuitive picture somewhat down: the intake manifold is partially opened; during the intake stroke of a four-stroke process, the piston moves rapidly moves downwards creating a short-term vacuum, which then induces a (short-term) vacuum in the intake manifold. Of course, since the manifold is at no point completely closed to the atmosphere, if this single stroke were completed and the system stopped, all the pressure would equalize and the vacuum would dissipate.

However, this vacuum *does not* dissipate because of the high velocity and multiple cylinders; thus by the time the pressure starts getting equalized, another vacuum starts getting created from another piston action, and so on.

Firstly, is this intuitive picture correct?

If so, my main issue is that I am not entirely sure how to mathematically describe this system (the effect of pressure reduction in the manifold). To simplify this so I can understand quantitatively the concepts, I have created an example problem below:

[image]

Here we have a single-cylinder setup which is open to the intake manifold. The box (manifold) has a volume of $V$, the cutout hole (throttle opening) on the left side of the box has an area of $A_{\text{th}}$, while the piston in the cylinder has a surface area of $A_p$. The cylinder has an internal radius of $r$, and the piston is being pulled down at a constant velocity of $v$ (though I don't anticipate it to be of value, say the cylinder's height is $h$).

**My main question is to mathematically describe the pressure situation inside of the intake manifold as the cylinder moves downwards in terms of the given variables**; please feel free to modify/add variables as necessary, as well as adjust the system: I chose the constant velocity because my intuition tells me that the manifold vacuum will be constant in that scenario, but I am entirely unsure of this.

In addition, while certainly an open-ended request, I would also like to understand how to describe this situation in its *entirety*. For example, what is the work done needed to keep  the piston moving at $v$? What are the forces on the piston? How does the Bernoulli principle affect the air moving through the system?

Thank you in advance for the assistance.

Comment: this is a post-doc effort.  I submit that this is more easily modeled than described with base equations, and that engine manufacturers have been improving their models for a century.

Comment: Will you be including the "smoothing" caused by an air filter?

Comment: The piston is not at a constant velocity - is has a maximum speed at a given crank angle and zero velocity twice.

Comment: @SolarMike I was not really considering the air filter smoothing. Also, I imposed the piston moving at a constant velocity as an initial condition, thus the work done to it would vary (say by an external pulling force)